# Issue with string concatenation - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a Sub that goes through 3 different worksheets and goes through a specific row in each of them (same row on each sheet) and if the cell does not equal 0 it collects some information about that cell. The three worksheets are large tables with dates of the month on the y-axis, and then different meters that we receive data from on the x-axis. Once my program finds a cell with a value that is not 0, it needs to grab information about its meter and what location its in. So I have this.

```
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value <> 0 Then
        data_piece = ""
        data_piece = Cells(cell.row - (day + 4), cell.Column) & ", " & 
Cells(cell.row - (day + 1)) & ", " & cell.Text
        MsgBox data_piece
        Call write_event(data_piece)
    End If

Next cell
```

For the first piece of data it finds it works perfect, and displays something to the affect of "Peace 20", Tank 1 to MSO, 500" but for every data point remaining on that sheet it wont display the first two bits of information. e.g: ",,500". When my program moves to the next sheet, it will display the first piece of data it finds perfectly, but then wont work for the rest of them on that sheet.

I'm stuck. Why this doesn't work?

Comment: Where is the loop where you iterate through the sheets?

Comment: Is it the `data_piece` variable you want to hold all of those concatenated values, or is it whatever the output to `write_event(data_piece)` is that should hold them all. Like... is it your `msgbox()` that you expecting all the concatenated stuff or some other place that isn't shown here in this snippet?

Comment: The loop where I iterate between sheets is not shown

Comment: @JNevill I use data_piece to initially store all these concatenated data and I run that through MsgBox just for debugging purposes. MsgBox will not be part of the fnished program. I send data_piece to another sub that handles the writing of all these concantenated strings to another sheet.

Comment: Well we would need to see that to help.  as your code is written it only effects the active sheet and if you are using `.Activate` to achieve this, it is the slow method and can be improved.

Comment: So each time you iterate a cell you set your `data_piece` back to empty. Then you fill it again with the new cell values. It's fine for debugging, but unless you capture the previous value (the value in the current loop) to some other variable or place in your sheet then it will be lost as soon as the next iteration hits.

Comment: The sub where I write the data isnt the problem. The problem is in this code block, as MsgBox is not displaying what I want it to. Ive been debugging with msgbox because I need to make sure Im sending the correct info to my write_event sub

Comment: @JNevill which is why I send it to write_event(data_piece). That subroutine handles the storing of my information on another sheet.

Comment: I believe the problem lies in how I am attempting to grab the bits of information related to my current cell.

Comment: Try using `Debug.Print cell.address & ": " & cell.value` to help you work out whether it is looking at the correct cell or not.

Comment: Which is my point. Your message box doesn't know what's already been stored. It only knows what's in that `data_piece` variable. If you are expecting to see everything that's been stored in your other sheet previous to the cell you are currently on then you are mistaken.

Comment: It would help to see a small example of your data and expected outcome.  It is hard to interpret what is going wrong without background.

Comment: Ive fixed it. Thanks for you help. I ended up hardcoding the row each cell should reference. A backhanded way of fixing the problem, but at least it works.